# mdl-js-ripple-effect causes event.target.value to become undefined in a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-design-lite, dom-events, create-react-app

When using vanilla mdl (`<script src="material.js"`> ) or using `react-mdl`, if I add the `mdl-js-ripple-effect` mdl class (or the ripple attribute with `react-mdl`) to a button, the `event.target.value` of the button element becomes undefined (the event handler is modifying state in react). Without the ripple effect, it works just fine. I can't find a solution other than ***not*** using the ripple effect; but that makes the button very boring. There seem to be issues with using react with mdl, but I thought someone might know more... (I'm using `create-react-app`)

The click handler:

```
  handleButtonClick(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({input: this.state.input + event.target.value});
  }
```

The "Key" React component using `react-mdl`:

```
function Key (props) {
    return(
      <Button raised colored ripple
        value={props.value}
        onClick={props.handleButtonClick}>
        {props.value}
      </Button>
    );
}
```

The same issue occurs if I use vanilla mdl with a `button` element:

```
function Key (props) {
    return(
        <button className="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised 
            mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--colored"
            value={props.value}
            onClick={props.handleButtonClick}>
          {props.value}
       </button>
    );
}
```

If I ***remove*** the ripple, then `event.target.value` is what it should be (`value={props.value}`) when the button is clicked. But ***with*** the ripple, it is undefined.

Anyone experienced this, or have an idea of why this is happening, or a work-around?

Comment: You can replicate this issue here - https://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/69z2wepo/68145/, in case anyone else wants to dive in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mdl-js-ripple-effect` class replaces the `button` element with a styled `span` element, removing it's `value` attribute.

You can access the `value` attribute via `this.props.value` instead.

Here's a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/69z2wepo/68146/) showing the values of `event.target.value` vs `this.props.value`.